# Is linking one project class to another project cause any performance or memory issue?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have linked some of the classes from one project to another project by using the below codes. This code added in my csproject file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\..\OrignialFile\ClassName.cs">
        <Link>Destination\ClassName.cs</Link>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

While running the application by adding these project files as reference i have faced some performance issue (i.e takes such long time for execution). Before linking i can able to do the same at minimal time. So i suspect linking classes could be reason for the performance issue. Is my suspection is correct, if it true please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Never assume, [always profile](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/). After profiling, 90% of my assumptions turned out to be wrong.

Comment: i agree with Uwe, and by the looks of what you are saying... i would so no. the issue is something else.

Comment: thanks..!here no need to check profiling because i can see huge different, can you please provide me whether the above code cause any issue relates to performance?

Comment: Profiling isn't meant to tell you whether there's a difference, it's meant to tell you where exactly the difference is. Basically, it would answer your question with facts where anybody else could just answer with speculation

Comment: We really can't tell anything about this. In the best case, all that including an extra file does is inflate the assembly size by zero, if it's an empty file. Worst case, it contains code that self-initializes (module initializer) and starts a thread that utilizes your CPU or other resources at 100%. In general, merely including a code file (where the resulting objects aren't accessed in any way, for example through reflection) does no harm whatsoever.

Comment: I have another one doubt, while debugging used set next statement (cntl+shift+F10) option. In this time one window raised which ask which project file should use(one is original, another one is linked project). Why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: The act of including another file **per se** shouldn't cause performance issues. Of course, **what** you are including might.

Comment: I have same doubt. Can anyone explain briefly regarding this.